# Interpretability of primitive recursive functions in Peano Arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic, peano-arithmetic

Let $R$ be a set of defining equations for primitive recursive functions successively built up from $s, +, \cdot$.

Is PA + $R$ interpretable in PA? (Interpretability understood in the sense of Tarski, Mostowski and Robinson.)
We know of course that all recursive functions are representable in PA, but I fail to see that this fact entails interpretability.

For instance, let $R$ consist only of the two equations that define exponentiation:
\begin{array}{l}
 x^0 = 1 \\
x^{s(y)} = x^y\cdot x
\end{array}

Suppose we have a possible definition D of exponentiation in PA:
\begin{equation} \forall xyz\big(x^y=z \leftrightarrow \mathit{Exp}(x,y,z)\big)\end{equation}

The formula
\begin{equation}
\tag{F}
x^{s(y)} = x^y\cdot x
\end{equation} is a theorem of PA + $R$. Hence, if PA + $R$ is indeed interpretable in PA, formula (F) is also a theorem of PA + D. I have difficulty seeing how the usual way of coding exponentiation in PA can deliver this.

Comment: You are asking whether primitive recursive arithmetic (PRA) has a direct interpretation in PA. It is well known that it does. Morever, this is almost immediate from the standard arithmetization of functions defined by primitive recursion using sequence coding. See e.g. Hájek & Pudlák, Lemma I.1.55.